# clang 3.8 .sancov file

Tags: c++, clang

I'm interested in clang SanitizerCoverage function. And I am processing with its documentation

```
% cat -n cov.cc
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  __attribute__((noinline))
     3  void foo() { printf("foo\n"); }
     4
     5  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     6    if (argc == 2)
     7      foo();
     8    printf("main\n");
     9  }
% clang++ -g cov.cc -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-coverage=func
% ASAN_OPTIONS=coverage=1 ./a.out; ls -l *sancov
main
-rw-r----- 1 kcc eng 4 Nov 27 12:21 a.out.22673.sancov
```

I use the same example, but I did not get a *.sancov file. 
And there seems no same question in stackoverflow.
Can anyone give me hint what's wrong with me?

Comment: This wasn't what you were looking for `a.out.22673.sancov`?

Comment: That was the documentation, I did not get that. Mine is "ls: cannot access '*sancov': No such file or directory"

Comment: The `ASAN_OPTIONS=coverage=1` prefix is required; nothing is generated without it.